# jQuery group matches and apply different styles to 1 and 2

Tags: jquery, filtering, each, loops

Got this code (working on it):

```
uniqueHead = {};
$("div.hleft h3").each(function () {
    var thiz = $(this)
    var thisValq = thiz.text();
    var thisVal = thisValq.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
    if(!(thisVal in uniqueHead) ) {
    uniqueHead[thisVal] = "";
    }
    else {
    $(this).parent().parent().css('border-color','red')
    }
});
```

That code applies to a list of search results where the search results of the group can be split ie "Result 1" that has the same name as "Result 2" can be at position 1 and 12.

What i would need to do is group all h3's that has the same text and then order them properly and apply different classes so that i only show result 1 in each group (and later can create a trigger that show similar results).

Imagine code like:

```
<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>One</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Two</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>One</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Two</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="blist">
    <div class="hleft">
    <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above isn't the "real" code but for the JS-part it works anyway. :)
I don't got any control of the backend so can't change how results are displayed hence the JS-solution for ordering etc.

Comment: Please show us the original HTML.  Kind of hard to write code that modifies the DOM without seeing what you start with.

Comment: Added example HTML. The original HTML is a bit too much to show since it got plenty of data within each <div class="blist">. The example is sort of the same without the bloat though. :)

Comment: And what do you want the resulting HTML to look like?

Comment: Like a list where each H3 act as an identifier to group all instances of .blist so that instance #2-xxx is inserted after instance #1.

See the, currently being worked on, demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbePd/)

Answer (score 1):

To handle the grouping part, I think you should store the DOM element corresponding to the first instance of each name you find (currently, you're just storying an empty string). Then, where you currently set the border to red, instead remove the duplicate element from the DOM and insert it after the original matching element. You can then add a class to each duplicate element hiding it.

Haven't tested this, but something like this should do the trick.

```
uniqueHead = {};
$("div.hleft h3").each(function () {
    var thiz = $(this);
    var thisValq = thiz.text();
    var thisVal = thisValq.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
    if(!(thisVal in uniqueHead) ) {
        uniqueHead[thisVal] = thiz;
    }
    else {
        // remove the element from the dom and place it after the original one
        var originalElement = uniqueHead[thisVal];
        originalElement.after($(this).remove().addClass("hiddenDuplicate"));
    }
});
```

How you then show duplicates at a later point is up to you. You could wrap each set of duplicates in a parent div, and then when a button within that div is clicked, show all child elements.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to add a class that would allow you to hide duplicates and information on showing the duplicates later.

Comment: That one works for sorting the H3's, however it is the parents of the h3's that should get sorted since each instance of .blist is a container. :)


See this jsfiddle:
**[link](http://jsfiddle.net/VbePd/).**


Attached the whole thing to a link so that one see before and after more clearly.

Comment: A problem that arises is that the DIV's get sorted in reverse. IE -- the last one gets added via .after(). That wouldn't be a problem but in my case each div has an attached pricetag from low to high. With the use of after() the most expensive item becomes #1 instead of being last.

Comment: What if you swap to using before() instead of after()?

Comment: Note the below "working" example and the parent().parent().
If before() it would add the iterations before each element which isn't desirable. What would be more desirable would be to check all matches and **then** add all matches using after() in on go.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of works. It is a bit ugly though. :)

```
uniqueHead = {};
$("div.hleft h3").each(function () {
    var thiz = $(this);
    var thisValq = thiz.text();
    var thisVal = thisValq.trim().toLowerCase().toString();
    if(!(thisVal in uniqueHead) ) {
        uniqueHead[thisVal] = thiz;
    }
    else {
        // remove the element from the dom and place it after the original one
        var originalElement = uniqueHead[thisVal];
        originalElement.parent().parent().after($(this).parent().parent().addClass("hiddenDuplicate"));
    }
});​
```

**jsFiddle link:**
http://jsfiddle.net/VbePd/3/

A problem with this though is that it reverses the order since after() isn't aware of contents already added. So 1,2,3,4 become 4,3,2,1.

Comment: A problem however is that the groups have attached prices sorted from low to high and with this method the grouped div's gets sorted in reversed due to ".after". Does anyone have any mod for that?